# How to load the custom CSS in SPFx Extension before the page load?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, style, page-load

We are loading a custom CSS using `SPComponentLoader` in SPFx Extension  to apply these styles in header. But while the page loads, the UI is not coming properly as the Custom CSS loads after the Page Load. Is there any way to load custom CSS from Extension before Page Load?

Answer (score 0):

I would  recommend use below approach to inject custom css in SPFx extension.

```
import { override } from '@microsoft/decorators';
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseApplicationCustomizer
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';

import * as strings from 'InjectCssApplicationCustomizerStrings';

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'InjectCssApplicationCustomizer';


export interface IInjectCssApplicationCustomizerProperties {
  cssurl: string;
}

export default class InjectCssApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<IInjectCssApplicationCustomizerProperties> {

  @override
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, `Initialized ${strings.Title}`);

    const cssUrl: string = this.properties.cssurl;
    if (cssUrl) {
        // inject the style sheet
        const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
        let customStyle: HTMLLinkElement = document.createElement("link");
        customStyle.href = cssUrl;
        customStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
        customStyle.type = "text/css";
        head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", customStyle);
    }

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

- Refer the below article for more details
- [Inject custom css in SPFx extension](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)

Comment: onInit method is delay loading in page. Due to this header styles is flashing.